# Ionic onclick scroll to bottom of a page not work

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3. When the user clicks on a button it should scroll down to the bottom of the page. Here is the code that I tried :

```
<div (click)='scrollDown()'>Change User Name</div>


<div>Now you can change your user name <div>
```

Logic :

```
 scrollDown() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 500);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the dimension of the page content to scroll to its bottom. Following is an example to scroll down on click event.

```
<div (click)='scrollDown()'>Scroll down</div>
```

.ts file

```
import {ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
import {Page,Content} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({  
  templateUrl: 'page/page.html',
})



export class Page {

    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

     constructor() {
     }
     scrollDown(){
        let dimensions = this.content.getContentDimensions();
        this.content.scrollTo(0, dimensions.scrollBottom, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir.it's not work for me. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContentDimensions' of undefined` error getting after add @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

Comment: Sorry, the@viewChild should be inside the class. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

worked like this,

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollToBottom() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.content.scrollToBottom) {
        this.content.scrollToBottom();
      }
    }, 400);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use @ViewChild annotation inside class for content.Then use scrollToBottom() on content when view is fully loaded inside a timeout function for avoiding glitch in the view.
Example code:

```
export class exPage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.content.scrollToBottom(300);
    });
   }
 }
```

`